# How to make website compatible with every browser

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I am trying to make new website and I would like to know how to make it compatible with cross-browser as now I am able to view my website perfectly with Google chrome and when I see the same with Firefox 7.0 it's looking very ugly and with IE 8 its looking better.So I would like to know how to make compatible.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: jQuery is the best to make cross-browser website!!!!. Please read this link: http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every browser will render differently many things, mainly as they render differently some CSS properties (you can check different browser rendering here www.w3schools.com/cssref/). A commonly used solution is to differentiate the CSS stilesheets for every possible browsers. You can detect the client browser via javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_browser.asp

and set different css again via javascript.

A complete example here:
http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Answer (score 0):

Each specific incompatibility will require a different solution. As a general guideline use frameworks such as jQuery and avoid browser-specific code, then when you find an incompatibility ask about that specific issue. Also, you should not aim for pixel-by-pixel compatibility between browsers, CSS is not actually designed for that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways is to use standardized code. Avoid using "HTML 5", because this still has a lot of browser specific implementations (as it is not yet a standard). HTML4 or XHTML1 should work on most browsers (Safari, Opera, Firefox, Chrome, IE7+), and show it more or less the same. As a web developer you should check with multiple browsers if your sites works ok. Using the ISO standards give you a good start: http://validator.w3.org/

Testing with a lot of browsers can be done using services like http://browsershots.org